# Nested setTimeouts runs once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm attempting to do a 'toaster' notification system with JS but it fails to run as expected.

Whenever there is an update either from nodeJS or AJAX relevant to the user I want to show a notification box that might nest if there are multiple notifications at the same time, kinda like facebook and be removed after 5 seconds of life, independent of the other notifications running at the moment.

However only the last notification will dissapear and be removed, the rest older ones will stay visible.... I can't find what is causing this.

This is my code which is within the mielikki object.

```
    var mielikki = {
    notifHooks: [],
    toaster : {
    notifCount : 0,
    launch : function(ops) {
        message = '';
        delay = 5000;
        msgType = 'generic';
        if("message" in ops) {
            message = ops.message;
        }
        if("delay" in ops) {
            delay = ops.delay;
        }
        if("msgType" in ops) {
            msgType = ops.msgType;
        }
        this.notifCount += 1;
        $('#toaster_template').clone().attr('id','notification-'+this.notifCount).html(message).appendTo('#notifications');
        var target = $("#notification-"+this.notifCount);
        var test = setTimeout(function() {  target.fadeOut("slow",function() { target.remove(); })},5000);
        mielikki.notifHooks.push( test );
    }
}
}
```

The div toaster_template is the base div to keep cloning for every new notification.

From any of the sources or the console will do something like this:

```
 mielikki.toaster.launch({'message' : 'test'});
```

But again, if the previous is run 2+ times simultaneously only the last/newest notification will do as expected.

Comment: Have you looked at John Papa's Toastr library? It's very simple and works great. http://www.johnpapa.net/toastr100beta/

Comment: Never hear of try and testing it now, so far so good, thanks! Just what I was attempting! - however is killing me why my code didn't work bummer.

Answer (score 0):

I see nothing wrong there, perhaps the timeouts are canceled somewhere else (with the `notifHooks` array you have), I thought it was a scope problem but there's no way to queue two timeouts with a shared element with the function you posted, not an answer to your problem but I did this test just to confirm that what you did has nothing wrong:

```js
function notification(message) {
  var notification = $('<div />').html(message);
  $(document.body).append(notification);
  
  setTimeout(function () {
    notification.fadeOut(500, function () { notification.remove() });
  }, 1000);
}

notification('hello');
notification('world');

setTimeout(function () {
  notification('1000ms');
}, 1000);

setTimeout(function () {
  notification('1500ms');
}, 1500);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Indeed - tested it too in multiple ways and it just doesn't work :( no sense in why it doesn't work.